# php if statement and paragraph code for placing content inside posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post, random

Hmm, sounds complicated

I have these codes

```
// counts words abd do something if words > 20
$words == 20; // number of characters to compare
if(str_word_count(get_the_content(),0)  < $words){
the_content();
}else{
the_content('Continue Reading...')
}

//codex wordpress code for showing random posts
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>


//code for placing adsense after paragraph 1
<?php
$paragraphAfter= 1;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++) {
if ($i == $paragraphAfter) { ?>
ad code
<?php
}
echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
} ?>
```

---

From these 3 codes I would like to make something like this

if txt =>100 words 
on paragraph = 2 add 
else do nothing

---

With these code (in case of long posts) I can reduce bounce

Answer (score 0):

```
if($i == 1 && strlen($content[$i]) >= 100)
{
    //your code
}
```

[strlen function](https://www.php.net/strlen)

Comment: I think this is not the solution.I need random posts to shows only in case the post have 100 words or more. Paragraph is the place where I want these random posts to show (inside post).